# Are there any python modules that take text and add python syntax highlighting to it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, syntax-highlighting

Are there any python modules that I could use with google app engine that take a string of code like this:

```
    <pre>
    a = 1
    while a < 10:
        print a
        a += 1
    </pre>
```

and then color the text like a basic python editor would (or like stack overflow)?

This would be highlighting the stuff inside the pre tag and would be displayed online.

Comment: If you just want to show highlighted code in a web page, [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) is also worthy to try. It's a frontend solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Pygments](http://pygments.org/).

> [Pygments] is a generic syntax highlighter for general use in all kinds of software such as forum systems, wikis or other applications that need to prettify source code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pygments http://pygments.org/